# Exteding magento core contact controllers issue

Tags: extend

I am following this:[turorial](http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/) to extend the magento core contact controller. I want to change get `postAction()` function.

So I created my module in local folder:
mynamespace/mymodule/controller/IndexController:

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers',"Mage_Contacts").DS."IndexController.php";

class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Contacts_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{
    public function indexAction(){
        parent::indexAction();
    }
    public function postAction(){

    }
}
```

then the mynamespace/mymodule/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <Mynamespace_MyModule>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Mynamespace_MyModule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <contacts>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <robot before="Mage_Contacts">Mynamespace_MyModule</robot>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </contacts>
        </routers>
    </frontend> 

</config>
```

then the Mynamespace_MyModule.xml from etc/modules:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Mynamespace_MyModule>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Mynamespace_MyModule>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

and it is actived. 
And i am getting this error: `Controller file was loaded but class does not exist` when i access the contact page. What did I do wrong at this point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have place the controller file `mynamespace/mymodule/controller/IndexController.php`

But the class was wrong in your code

```
Mynamespace_Mymodule_Contacts_IndexController
```

You have to move that controller to contacts folder

```
i.e., mynamespace/mymodule/controller/contacts/IndexController.php
```

or else

remove the `contacts` from the class name
i.e., Mynamespace_Mymodule_IndexController

**Note:** Don't forget to add `<?php` at starting of the controller file

Answer (score 0):

Your controller file name should be  `Mynamespace/Mymodule/controllers/IndexController.php` (notice the `s` in `controllers`) and your class name should be `Mynamespace_Mymodule_IndexController`